# multiple version android apps running after upgrade pre-installed app

Tags: android, upgrade

pre-installed app: version code is 2, mobile's android 5.0.2, path /system/app.
newly installed app: version code is 3, mobile's android 5.0.2, path /data/app.

After renaming some classes, I release an app of Version Code 3 on the device. But I find both v2 and v3 versions are running at the same time. Sometimes foo() of v2 is called, while othertimes foo() of v3 is called. And this state comes to end after rebooting my device.

```

```
18:30:24  calling  foo()-v2
18:32:34  calling  foo()-v3
18:35:05  calling  foo()-v2
...
```

```

It seems after installing a newer version of the app. Two versions are kept in memory.

Is there anyone can tell why the pre-installed and newly installed app are running at the same time?

Comment: Did you change the main package name of the application?

Comment: no, package name is kept the same. And it seems only the higher version app runs if I reboot the device.